# What ports are needed to be enabled on a Linux web server by Apache tomcat?

Tags: linux, tomcat, webserver

We have a Linux server running only Apache Tomcat on it. What ports are needed to be enabled on Linux VM?

A list of enabled ports on that machine and a brief explanation of why we need them would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Tomcat can be configured to use whatever ports you want it to use. In a typical Tomcat deployment, you will want to define two types of ports:

1. The [shutdown port](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/server.html#Common_Attributes). This is used to shutdown Tomcat, and it can be disabled so that you need to use an OS signal or other method to shut down your Tomcat instance. Tomcat will, by default, only bind to the localhost interface, so you do not have to (and, specifically *do not want*) to open this port to the public.
2. Any number of [connector ports](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes). These are the ports that are used to serve traffic for web requests. Tomcat supports HTTP and AJP protocols, and each of those listen on a TCP/IP port of your choosing. By default/convention, a non-encrypted HTTP connector listens on port 8080, an encrypted HTTPS connector listens on port 8443, and an AJP connector listens on port 8009.
   You are free to set these ports to anything you'd like, and it is *these* ports that you will typically need to make public through your firewall or other similar defenses.